# if statement using jquery selectors and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, checkbox

I have a form with two text input fields and a series of checkboxes.

There is a variable *fields* which stores some arrays with data pertaining to the selected fields. I have hardcoded the values into the script with no problem but I cannot seem to find out how to properly compose an if statement to check the status of the checkboxes and only use those values, rather than hardcoding the selected fields.

```js
var start, end, fields;

$(function() {
  $("#form1").submit(function(event) {
    var endD = $("#endDate").val();
    end = endD;
    var startD = $("#startDate").val();
    start = startD;

    //fields = ['PM1','PM2.5','PM10'];


    //if $("#PM1").is("checked"))){
    //fields = ["PM1"];
    //}


    if ($("PM1").attr("checked")) {
      fields = ["PM1"];
    }


    event.preventDefault();

    build_graph();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  Start Datetime:<br>
  <input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" class="Date" placeholder="YYYYMMDD-HHMM"><br> End Datetime <br>
  <input type="text" name="startDate" id="endDate" class="Date" placeholder="YYYYMMDD-HHMM"><br> Parameter
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="PM1">PM1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="PM2.5" checked>PM2.5<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="PM10">PM10<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="Temp">Temperature<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="Humidity">Humidity<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="Pressure">Pressure<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="WindSpeed">Wind Speed<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="Direction">Direction<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="parameter" id="RainVolume">Rain Volume<br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: A lot of us are developers, not literature gurus, So keep you commentary to a minimal and you may get a better response. -How does telling us about your work environment add to the situation? TLDR;

Comment: The uncommented conditional statement is a missing a `#` in the selector

Comment: @SethMcClaine noted and will do in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select only the checked checkbox, using a JQuery selector : 
`$('.myCheckboxs:checked')`
this will give you only the checked one.

Comment: And this would select all elements with the class "mycheckboxs" which were checked like you said? I'm going to try and work this out for a couple minutes and I'll return when I've something presentable. Thank you

Comment: this will return each checkbox with the class myCheckboxs that are checked, if you don't want to use a class, you could always use this `$('.theClassOfMyForm input[type="checkbox"]:checked)`

Comment: So two ways of going about this immediately come to mind. One to somehow pass each of those selected elements id's directly into the fields variable as an array. Two is to make an if statement with something that would loop through each and check if it was if it was checked with a modification of that selector in a much more clunky way.

Comment: here i made a fiddle so you can understand my solution https://jsfiddle.net/dyomLqzz/5/

Comment: In my case, we get each selected check box Id into an array. I use `join` to make a beautiful string out of it but you can use them how ever you like

Comment: I'm looking at the fiddle and trying to play around with things. Why did you add the results class to the form and what does the span do to that class? I also cannot figure out the finer details of these two lines `var checkedCheckbox = $('#form1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() { return this.id; }).get()
    $('.result').html(checkedCheckbox.join(", "));
  })`

Comment: the span has noting to do, it is just to show the output. the first line extract the Id of each checked checkbox. the second line is also useless, it allow us to create a string of the element contained in the list of ids.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes so much more sense now.

Comment: Glad i could help !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147871/discussion-between-hotmaildotcom1-and-nicolas).

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can properly check if a checkbox is checked like:

```
if($('#mycheckbox').prop("checked")){
  // it´s checked
}
```

my tip, use this function that serializes your form into an object

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

you can then serialize your form like this:

```
fields = $("#form1").serializeObject()
```

all input values and checkboxes that are checked will occur as property

Comment: This is probably exactly what I need to do but it is over my level of understanding as far as execution. I will try and get back to you after I do some reading and understand what all is going here and see if I can implement it properly.

Comment: it is allready possible to serialize a form to JSON, https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: no by default it will create an URI-query-String instead of an object

Comment: @hotmaildotcom1 you´re welcome, it´s a little extension of jquery so you can call `.serializeObject()` on a jQuery object, it will basically turn all your form inputs and their values into a javascript object, the name attribute of the input is the key and the value is the value ;)  (ideal to send to backend and avoid code repitition like you do )